# Rails display routes helper prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the route prefix for the current page that a rails application is on. I know that you can get the controller & action info, and you can also get the path with:

```
request.env['PATH_INFO']
```

But there doesn't seem to be an environment variable for the prefix, that or i've missed it somewhere along the line. Is this possible, or do you have to find it through some hacky way using the controller & action / route?

it's almost as if i'm after a:

```
request.env['PATH_PREFIX']
```

or a:

```
get_prefix(controller_name, action_name)
```

SOLVED (In slim):

```
- Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(request) do |route, matches, param|
  => route.name
```

Comment: what is route prefix? can you provide an example?

Comment: I found the answer in the edit above, but by the route prefix i meant the name each route gets when you run "rake routes". There may be a different way of explaining it that i would love to hear :)

Comment: for example, is `new` route prefix of `new_article_path`?

Comment: Also, if you just want to keep track of the prefixes while developing, you can use this gem that makes it easy: https://rubygems.org/gems/restful_routing